# Search Issue after migration

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

I have migrated on SP 2016 environment and configure fresh SSA on same.
when I am searching for anything it gives below error

The HTTP service located at http://ServerName:PortNo/9e38a353839448f0b55fe1b52d43fb30/SearchService.svc is unavailable. This could be because the service is too busy or because no endpoint was found listening at the specified address. Please ensure that the address is correct and try accessing the service again later.

When I am looking for Search Service in IIS under the SharePoint Web Service the ID is different from what I am getting in the above error that is 9e38a353839448f0b55fe1b52d43fb30.

I have updated the Search Center URL under Search Settings.

Please suggest useful solution.

Comment: How have you migrated Search Service application? We have had problems with SSA migration in test environment 2013->2016 as well. After a lot of digging we have created a powershell script which migrates SSA without problems. Is deleting SSA and remigration a possible solution for you?

Comment: I didn't migrated the SSA. I had set up a new SP 2016 environment, migrated the content by using DB attach detach method and created the new/fresh SSA using Powershell. Now SSA is running fine and also crawling the relevant content properly. I am facing the above issue when I am trying to search anything from SharePoint site/portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proxy was not showing in the Service application list for Search Service application but at the same time it was showing in Powershell after running the below command 
**Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy**

So I have delete the proxy and recreated the SSA using Powershell and the issue is resolved.